# Artifact Deployer Plugin Alternative

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We are using the artifact deployer plugin in a Jenkins freestyle job, and recently Jenkins is displaying warnings about the plugin no longer being safe to use.

This plugin is no longer being distributed according to their wiki site [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/ArtifactDeployer+Plugin)

Does anyone know of any alternative plugins, or ways in a freestyle job to copy content from one location to another (on same node)

Thanks

Comment: Is it a Linux node or Windows node?

Comment: Using a linux node

Comment: Do you only want to achieve copying your deloyable from one location to another inside the same node?

Comment: yes - contents of one directory to another on the same node

Answer (score 1):

To copy all the contents from one directory to another directory in a `Linux` system use the following command:

`cp -a /path/to/source_dir/. /path/to/dest_dir/`

You can add an `Execute shell step` in in your job configuration in `Build` section and add the above command into it.